# No module name A error even after adding the path to sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, init

I have the following package structure:

```
A/
  a1.py
  __init__.py
   B/
    __init__.py
    a2.py
   C/
    a3.py
    __init__.py
```

Now I would like to import a from from `a2.py` into `a3.py`. Assume my function name is `func_a2`. so I go to module `a3.py` and I write

```
from A.a2 import func_a2
```

I get the `error: no module name A`
I try to add the A to the sys.path using `sys.path.append('..')`
But again I receive the same error.
I am running it from terminal by going C folder and type

```
python a3.py
```

so it is not running from jupyter notebook or anything.
I have read articles in the internet and browse through questions here but still do not know how to make this work. Can someone first explain what is the problem and how I can solve this error?

Comment: Since you are running it from `C` folder that's why you are getting module not found error which is obvious. Try `python C/a3.py` from folder `A`. Your working directory should be the top level directory in your project files. Otherwise you will have to set your working directory as `A` before running `python a3.py` from folder `C`

Comment: My working directory is now A and still the above command gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

A is the grandmother for a2.py. Try to add it to sys.path

```
ROOT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1]

sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, ''))
```

You can adjust level by passing parent[0], parent[1], etc. and check the changes to sys.path by printing sys.path just before the erroneous import statement.